# Is there anything like, or similar to a routed version of the INPC interface?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, routed-events

Using RoutedEvents, you can do things such as have a single control which hosts thousands of child controls, but rather than subscribe to MouseDown on each child, you set a handler on the root control and inspect the 'sender' property to find which child was actually clicked on.

I'm wondering if there's any such thing for INPC objects, or if not, can one be created.

For instance, if you have a collection which contains thousands of objects which all implement INPC, currently you have to subscribe to each and every one individually.  I'm wondering if there's a way around that.

The only thing I can think of is in the setter property for these properties you're interested in, in addition to raising the standard INPC notification, call a delegate in the containing collection and have the collection raise the appropriate notification.  That way the consumer would just have to subscribe to a single handler on the collection for any of its children.

My hesitation here is if you're going to do that, why not just make that collection subscribe to the children itself, then re-raise the notification from the collection?  My thought however is that calling a delegate directly from the specific setters you're interested in avoids string comparison in the PropertyChanged handler that would delegate such notifications.

> Note: This is pseudo-code typed off the top of my head so it may not compile.  It's to illustrate a concept/idea, not to be an example of actual code.

```
public class ItemCollection : ObservableCollection<Item>
{
    public EventHandler ChildItemPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName);

    internal void RaiseChildItemPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        var childItemPropertyChanged = ChildItemPropertyChanged;
        if(childItemPropertyChanged != null)
            childItemPropertyChanged(sender, propertyName);
    }

}

public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ItemCollection OwningCollection;
    public Item(ItemCollection owningCollection)
    {
        OwningCollection = owningCollection;
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get{ return _name; }
        set
        {
            if(_name == value)
                return;

            _name = value;

            PropertyChanged(this, "Name");

            OwningCollection.RaiseChildItemPropertyChanged(this, "Name");
        }
    }
}
```

Thoughts?